# How to pass my element 1 to element 2 in a click (not find on the forum) explanation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this :

```
this.questionnaire.Profil: {p1: {…}, p2: {…}, p3: {…}, p4: {…}, p5: {…}}
```

How could I display the next element after click.

My code :

```
for(var question in this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"]){
  this.current=this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"][question];
  console.log(question, " -> " + this.questionnaire.Profil);
  break;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: You mean a carousel?

Comment: no no in fact it is a group question (without knowing how much it has question) .. my page displays the question 1 (it's done) and I will like a variable or whatever, so that when I click on next I go from p1 => next element (I answer question) I click on next I go from p2 => next element

Comment: You can create element for all object property and show only one element. On click of element show the next element and hide the old one.

Comment: yes it's that kind of thing that I need but I do not know how to set up I start :/

Comment: inside objects, I get them back already, I just need something to pass element 1 => element and element 2 => next element ... and so on until he has more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate your object using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

**A pure JS solution :**

```js
var questions = {p1: {question:"question1"}, p2: {question:"question2"}, p3: {question:"question3"}, p4: {question:"question4"}, p5: {question:"question5"}};
var current = Object.keys(questions)[0];
function getNextQuestion(){
  console.log(questions[current].question);
  var keys = Object.keys(questions);
  var index = keys.indexOf(current);
  if(keys[index + 1] && questions[keys[index + 1]]){ //there is a next element
    current = keys[index + 1];
  } else {
    current = keys[0];
  }

}
```

```html
   
<button class="btn-next" ion-button required onclick="getNextQuestion()" round block>Next</button>
```

Comment: yes, but I do not have the exact number of questions; and it's dynamic is to say that I'm worth doing (not required) incrementing a variable to move from p1 to p2 (group of questions it has 13 with a different number of questions, a next button for all) in javascript not in jquery unfortunately: /

Comment: my html code : <button class="btn-next"  ion-button required (click)="getNextQuestion()" round block>Next</button>

Comment: inside objects, I get them back already, I just need something to pass element 1 => element and element 2 => next element ... and so on until he has more

Comment: I think that I don't really understand your request! I've edited the answer, take a look.

Comment: I am not the exact number of question;
and I do not need to get the inside of the object back;
just need to go from element 1 to element 2 of the object just p1 => p2 not need the inside

Comment: @JohnFitze, what about this solution ?!

Comment: is it possible to put it in mouth form with FOR ?? we get closer ^^

Comment: but I do not go to the next item

Comment: Why do you need the `For`?  Does the `P1`,`P2`.. contains more than one question?

Comment: no but I will want to make a loop so that when I click on next I go to the next element I stay at element 1 with your code /:

Comment: No, it does not stay in element 1! After every click, youll see `question1`, `question2`, `question3` ....

Comment: unfortunately my button does not change the page

Comment: When you click on the above buttton `Run Code Snippet`, do you see what you want? If so, please post how you used this code in your project..

Comment: yes hiding the previous question and next question to each click I go to the next one (but it does not work your code): o